# NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary with multiple keys, data structure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-structures, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to create a data structure for three fields.  One method can grab two fields from a sqlite database.  Another method grabs data using the two fields from another sqlite database.  What is a good way to store the data?  The three fields I need are of type:

```
NSString, key: @"Name"
NSInteger, key: @"ID"
NSArray, key: @"Info"
```

I thought I would do an array of dictionaries.  So in the first method, I get the NSString and NSInteger, create a dictionary, and create an array of those dictionaries out of it.  Then I got stuck thinking how I even print out the data for a NSMutableDictionary with two keys (question #1).

Then the second thing I thought was, can I then use the Name, ID fields to get the other piece of data from another table, and add a new key/value pair into the dictionary. I wasn't sure if that could be done (question #2).

And I didn't know if there was just a better way to approach this with a different data structure (question #3).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "print out"?  You can, of course, use `description` to do a "diagnostic dump" of the whole structure, but if you want to print things in a nice, defined format you need write the logic to do it.  Basically no more difficult with NSDictionarys/NSArrays that with regular C-style structures, though.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yeah I was trying to print out the values for the NSDictionary when there are multiple keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for the data items, an iVar for each Name, ID, Info.  Then you have a lot of flexibility.

While an NSDictionary initially often seems to be an easy solution it is generally better to create a class which is really rather easy and usability is generally better.